# How to write ASN1 encoding in python using PyASN INTEGER (1..MAX)?

Tags: python, password-encryption, asn.1, pbkdf2

I am trying to implement some encoding in Python using PyASN libraries. I have to define a class where I should implement the following :

```
pbkdf2params ::= SEQUENCE {
salt OCTET STRING,
iterationCount INTEGER (1..MAX),
keyLength INTEGER (1..MAX)
}
```

And the python class I have defined is as follows:

```
class pbkdf2params(univ.Sequence):
 componentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(
   namedtype.NamedType('salt', univ.OctetString()),
   namedtype.NamedType('iterationCount', univ.integer(1,MAX)), 
   namedtype.NamedType('keyLength', univ.integer(1, MAX))
   )
```

But I don't think this is correct especially for integer(1..MAX) . What have I missed? What is the MAX value it takes in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a [value range constraint](http://pyasn1.sourceforge.net/constraints.html#1.4.2) to Integer object like this:

```
from pyasn1.type import univ, namedtype, constraint

class Pbkdf2params(univ.Sequence):
    componentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(
        namedtype.NamedType('salt', univ.OctetString()),
        namedtype.NamedType('iterationCount', univ.Integer().subtype(subtypeSpec=constraint.ValueRangeConstraint(1,MAX)), 
        namedtype.NamedType('keyLength', univ.Integer().subtype(subtypeSpec=constraint.ValueRangeConstraint(1, MAX))
    )
```

Whenever you attempt to initialize Integer with an out-of-range value, an exception will be thrown.